# Сократить и упростить код для чтения JS

Tags: javascript

Как я могу упростить эту функцию? Не особо важно за что она отвечает и зачем нужна главное сократить её и упростить для чтения

```
        function move(direction) {
        if (direction === moveSet.right && heroPos.y !== cols - 1) {
            if (area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y + 1] === '*') {
                colCount +=1;
                console.log('Собрано ' + colCount + ' сундуков')
            }
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.y += 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.right && heroPos.y === cols - 1) {
            console.log('Там стенка');
        } if (direction === moveSet.left && heroPos.y !== 0) {
            if (area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y - 1] === '*') {
                colCount +=1;
                console.log('Собрано ' + colCount + ' сундуков')
            }
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.y -= 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.left && heroPos.y === 0) {
            console.log('Там стенка');
        } if (direction === moveSet.down && heroPos.x !== rows - 1) {
            if (area[heroPos.x + 1][heroPos.y] === '*') {
                colCount +=1;
                console.log('Собрано ' + colCount + ' сундуков')
            }
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.x += 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.down && heroPos.x === rows - 1) {
            console.log('Там пол')
        } if (direction === moveSet.up && heroPos.x !== 0) {
            if (area[heroPos.x - 1][heroPos.y] === '*') {
                colCount +=1;
                console.log('Собрано ' + colCount + ' сундуков')
            }
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.x -= 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.up && heroPos.x === 0) {
            console.log('Там потолок')
        } 
        
        render();
    }
```

Comment: Лучше бы всё же описали, что делает эта функция. Чем подробнее, тем лучше.

Answer (score 0):

```
function move(direction) {
  switch (direction) {
    case moveSet.right:
      moveToRight();
      break;
    case moveSet.left:
      moveToLeft();
      break;
    case moveSet.down:
      moveToDown();
      break;
    case moveSet.up:
      moveToUp();
      break;
  }

  render();
}

function moveToRight() {
  if (heroPos.y !== cols - 1) {
    changePosition(0, 1);
  } else {
    console.log('Там стенка');
  }
}

function moveToLeft() {
  if (heroPos.y !== 0) {
    changePosition(0, -1);
  } else {
    console.log('Там стенка');
  }
}

function moveToDown() {
  if (heroPos.x !== rows - 1) {
    changePosition(1, 0);
  } else {
    console.log('Там пол')
  }
}

function moveToUp() {
  if (heroPos.x !== 0) {
    changePosition(-1, 0);
  } else if (direction === moveSet.up && heroPos.x === 0) {
    console.log('Там потолок')
  }
}

function pickUpChest() {
  colCount +=1;
  console.log('Собрано ' + colCount + ' сундуков')
}

function changePosition(x, y) {
  area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
  heroPos.x += x;
  heroPos.y += y;

  if (area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] === '*') {
    pickUpChest();
  }

  area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
}
```

Например вот так.

Чуть позже опубликую еще 1 версию

Answer (score 0):

можно еще как-то так, но мне нравится больше ваиант из другого ответа

```
function move(direction) {
  if (isMoveToBorder[direction]) {
      if (isMoveToBorder[direction](heroPos, cols, rows)) {
        console.log(borderMessage[direction]);
      } else {
        changePositions[direction](area, heroPos);
      }
  }

  render();
}

const borderMessage = {
  right: 'Там стенка',
  left: 'Там стенка',
  up: 'Там потолок',
  down: 'Там пол',
}

const isMoveToBorder = {
  right: (heroPos, cols) => heroPos.y === cols - 1,
  left: (heroPos, cols) => heroPos.y === cols - 1,
  down: (heroPos, cols, rows) => heroPos.x === rows - 1,
  up: heroPos => heroPos.x === 0,
}

const changePositions = {
  left: (area, heroPos) => changePosition(area, heroPos, 0, -1),
  right: (area, heroPos) => changePosition(area, heroPos, 0, 1),
  down: (area, heroPos) => changePosition(area, heroPos, 1, 0),
  up: (area, heroPos) => changePosition(area, heroPos, -1, 0),
}

function pickUpChest() {
  colCount +=1;
  console.log('Собрано ' + colCount + ' сундуков');
}


function changePosition(area, heroPos, x, y) {
  area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
  heroPos.x += x;
  heroPos.y += y;

  if (area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] === '*') {
    pickUpChest();
  }

  area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
}
```